# ModuleNotFound, No Module name : scipy.sparse._csr

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, python-3.6, pickle

I have installed dependancies with scipy 1.5.4 in my docker container using python 3.6
But When I run the my python3 script I get this error I have running the script with python 3.10.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "PipelineAPI5_modified1.py", line 2161, in process_audio
    dataframe_dict = main()
  File "PipelineAPI5_modified1.py", line 700, in main
    save_as_xlsx()
  File "PipelineAPI5_modified1.py", line 1985, in save_as_xlsx
    intent_label1 = transcription_kaldi_log.predict_intent_casual(y)
  File "/kaldi_docker/echo/Audio_Analytics/transcription_kaldi_log.py", line 341, in predict_intent_casual
    vectorizer = pickle.load(open('/kaldi_docker/echo/Audio_Analytics/Files/intent_casual_phrases/vectorizer.sav', 'rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'
```

please help if anyone can resolve this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you tried installing the same scipy library version as the one you had with 3.6?   Library differences between versions would tend to throw a wrench in the load()

Comment: On an upto date `scipy`, importing `._csr` works.  I'm not familiar with the organization of the `sparse` package, but it has been reworked in recent versions (trying move from 'matrix' to 'array').  So it's possible that `_csr` did not exist in the older configuration.  So an object pickled with 3.10 might not be loadable in 3.6.